# Sim card factory reset my S7 without asking permission

Tags: factory-reset, data-recovery

Used the device for a long while (without sim) amassing a huge number photos and work files very important to me....

finally put an active sim card in. Without any prompts, phone begins downloading an update, then powers down to 'install update' then proceeds to reset and 'erasing data' ....

Boots up into setup as if i just got the phone.

All my apps, photos, data gone.

A) Is it possible to recover my data

B) why on earth did it do thiss

[Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge with Telus (Canada) sim card]

Comment: Never heard of a forced update that does a factory reset... Or an OTA update that erases user data at all. Very peculiar, updates on an unlocked device come directly from the manufacturer, not carrier.

Comment: The device was just in the process of being unlocked; moments prior I had requested the carrier perform an unlock of my phone.   They asked me to insert their sim card from my other device as part of that process.   So when I inserted the card, it took a few moments but once it connected to the network, bam factory reset started with no prompts.  So perhaps the unlock procedure was also a factor in the unexpected FR.

Comment: Unlocking the bootloader performs a factory reset, not unlocking the carrier/SIM... very odd

Comment: Is it possible the carrier and Samsung have a unique functionality coded such that when the carrier's sim card is inserted into a 'new' device (ie- just unboxed) that it automatically downloads the latest updates and then FR ?  Maybe the carrier wanted a way to expedite new setups (ie- at their kiosks or stores) and so hence this feature.  And they just overlooked the fact that people may actually use the device before inserting a sim.

Answer (score 0):

A.) Unfortunatelly if you didn't made a backup from your pictures, apps, data it's all gone.

B.) I'm a bit confused because your phone won't be download and install any system update without prompt. The auto download part is hardly possible but the auto-install part, is quite difficult to believe.

Comment: How about advanced recovery options?  By the way, when it happened, my carrier was also in the process of performing an unlock (I had just requested them to do it, they obliged for a small fee).

Comment: So not the SIM card changing coused the FR but the unlocking process.

Comment: Well that's the thing, I don't know.  One or the other, or combination of both. When I requested the unlock my carrier said nothing about an impending factory reset.